# Number plus string in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The expression

```
SELECT (6000.03 + '00') AS res;
```

gives the result `6000.03`, but the expression

```
SELECT (6000.00 + '00') AS res;
```

gives the result `6000`. Why is the fractional part discarded in the second expression?

Comment: If you need to simple add values, use CAST() [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: @S.Kadakov, Thank you, but no, I want to understand why it happens.

Comment: Its discarded because it has no significance whatsoever.  If you want to view it, you would use a formatted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a string to a number without changing the data type.
MySQL will auto-convert the '00' into a number since you have no explicit date definition in your select.

It will discard the fractional part in the second example as 6000.00 = 6000 = an integer value.

If you do this manipulation in a tables column that is defined as decimal, the fractional part won't be discarded as MySQL won't override your column definitions.

Comment: If I do this manipulation in a tables column that is defined as decimal(12, 2),  the fractional part will be discarded as well as in above example...